# Directly accessing Angular 2 routes on bluemix: 404

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud

I'm developing an angular 2, which is deployed to IBM bluemix.

After deployment I can no longer access paths like myangular2app.mybluemix.net/somePath directly, which leads to a 404 page, while it works fine when run locally. I can only open myangular2app.mybluemix.net, and from there use the app's navigation to access whatever path I want, but how can I access those paths directly by URL on bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the webserver you have running on `IBM bluemix`. Depending on the webserver you need to change the configuration that it redirects all 404 none file requests to `index.html`. For instance if you have `nginx` running, you need to edit the server block to contain something like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```